# What Items Can i sell at my seed website i am making that isn't patented?

Tags: germination

I am making an online shop that sells seeds. I am wanting to know what seeds i am able to sell. Right now all i have is jack-o-lantern pumpkins,swan gourds, and tiger strip pumpkin. What else am i able to sell. Please answer soon! Thanks.